# How to combine the icons of different icon sets into a new one?

Tags: wingpanel, themes, icons

I would like combine two icon sets into one new icon set. Meaning I want the wingpanel icons (sound,battery,wifi,etc) and the application toolbar icons (geary,scratch,etc) from the default elementary icon set but combined with the application icons (as seen in plank or slingshot) from Faba-Mono or Numix.

In my theory I would like to just copy some folders together to a new folder and select a new the icon theme in elementary tweaks.

Can something like this be done and where are those folders located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a copy of the original icon set you want to edit to a working folder in your `/home` folder, then edit the name of the folder so you know it's your own custom setup.
Within this folder is an `index.theme` file, which you can edit with your text editor of choice. At the beginning of the `index.theme` file will be text similar to below.

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=My-theme-name
Comment=Smooth modern theme designed to be intuitive.

Inherits=elementary,Numix-Circle
```

You want to change the theme name, typically the name you chose for the folder name.
Notice the Inherits section, this is where you place the names of the themes you would like to include with this theme.
The way the icon themes work is typically whatever is missing by this theme will then be Inherited by the next theme assigned in `Inherits=`
You must use the name that is associated from within the index.theme file of designated theme(s), not the folder name.

Within the folder of your main theme directory if you **do not** want the icons on the panel, then find the folder(s) that are labeled `panel` and `status` then delete them. Also if there is no panel folder, then panel icons will usually be found in the `apps` folder with a `-panel` designation on the icon file. Application toolbar icons are typically in folder(s) `actions`.  So if you do not want the action buttons of the main theme, then delete the folder(s) labeled `actions`
This same process can be applied to individual files within each folder, if there are individual icons you do not like.

Once you have finished your edits, place the icons in `~/.icons` first for a test run before moving them to `/usr/share/icons` if you want the theme available to all groups/users. If you don't have a `.icons` folder then just make one. You can leave them in `~/.icons` as long as you assign read permissions to all groups, if you just want to use them on your account plus have them show up with sudo applications. `$ chmod -R 744 ~/.icons` or `755` will work.

This method will work for most, if not all distributions, so making a backup of your custom theme(s) is a good idea.

Comment: Nice, this is just what I wanted. I did a quick test of this method and it worked out of the box.

Now I just have to find a way to clean up all the mess I created while changing all the icons manually with MenuLibre (dublicate and missing icons in plank).

Answer (score 2):

The files of the icon themes you have installed and all that come by default are saved under `/usr/share/icons`. From there you can copy the ones you like and combine them into a new one.

There is a software which could help you do that is `menulibre`, you can select specific icons that you want to change.
You can install it using:

`sudo apt-get install menulibre`

If you can't install that way  you can use this ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

Comment: Nice I was able to dublicate the elementary theme by copying the folder and editing the index.theme file. The problem is that they have a completly different folder structure as it seems so it will be hard to overwrite the files easily. Isnt there a software alternative for this?

Comment: @hrvstr I edit my answer given you information about a software that you could use.

Comment: Okay, I went through the painful process of changing all of them manually. The new problem now is that all applications have a dublicate (and sometimes missing) icon in plank. I know this problem from back when I used chrome but haven't experienced it with any other apps.

I already checked if StartupWMClass is correct in some of the .desktop files and they are all identical to the ones I get from doing "xprop WM_CLASS" in terminal.


I uploaded a screenshot here (you can see system-monitor, terminal and hourglass dublicated): http://i.imgur.com/B9dgo67.png

Answer (score 0):

Edit file of app you want to customize in `/usr/share/applications/` folder. Open it by text editor and set `Icon=/path/filename.svg`.

In my case it was `Icon=/home/hp2560/Documents/appsicons/sublime-text.svg`.